# AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'testing'

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

Last week I was able to run programs in Python 3.7.2 just fine.

This morning I come in, run the same program and get error

`AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'testing'`

I did fresh uninstall and install of python 3.7.2

Then I did `pip3 install -U scikit-learn scipy matplotlib`, ran same program(s) and still getting this error.

Spent the whole morning googling, and trying different things (and of course, rebooted machine, checked PATH)

Please help!!!!!!

## Code (other code triggers as well)

```
# Assigning features and label variables

# First Feature
weather=['Sunny','Sunny','Overcast','Rainy','Rainy','Rainy','Overcast','Sunny','Sunny',
'Rainy','Sunny','Overcast','Overcast','Rainy']

# Second Feature
temp=['Hot','Hot','Hot','Mild','Cool','Cool','Cool','Mild','Cool','Mild','Mild','Mild','Hot','Mild']

# Label or target varible
play=['No','No','Yes','Yes','Yes','No','Yes','No','Yes','Yes','Yes','Yes','Yes','No']


# Import LabelEncoder

from sklearn import preprocessing

# creating labelEncoder

le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()

# converting string labels into numbers

weather_encoded = le.fit_transform(weather)

print(weather_encoded)

# converting string labels into numbers

temp_encoded = le.fit_transform(temp)

label = le.fit_transform(play)

# combining weather and temp into a single list of tuples

features = list(zip(weather_encoded,temp_encoded))


from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

model = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3)

# Train the model using the training sets

model.fit(features, label)

# Predict Output

predicted = model.predict([[0,2]]) #0:Overcast, 2:Mild

print(predicted)
```

## Traceback

```
e:\ML>python knn.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "knn.py", line 16, in <module>
    from sklearn import preprocessing
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 64, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 187, in <module>
    from .testing import Tester
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\testing\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from ._private.utils import *
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\testing\_private\utils.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tempfile import mkdtemp, mkstemp
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\tempfile.py", line 45, in <module>
    from random import Random as _Random
  File "e:\ML\random.py", line 4, in <module>
    from sklearn import datasets
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\datasets\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .base import load_breast_cancer
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\datasets\base.py", line 20, in <module>
    from ..utils import Bunch
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from scipy.sparse import issparse
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\__init__.py", line 230, in <module>
    from .base import *
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\base.py", line 9, in <module>
    from scipy._lib._numpy_compat import broadcast_to
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\_lib\_numpy_compat.py", line 16, in <module>
    _assert_warns = np.testing.assert_warns
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'testing'
```

Comment: We'd need, at the very least, the full traceback, and preferably the code that triggers the exception.

Comment: However, the most likely reason for the error is that you created a local file `numpy.py` or package directory `numpy/` that masks the installed library. The traceback would help us confirm this.

Comment: Also see [Importing installed package from script raises "AttributeError: module has no attribute" or "ImportError: cannot import name"](//stackoverflow.com/q/36250353)

Comment: Hellp @MartijnPieters Ok, I posted one of the programs (among several ML programs), plus traceback. I dunno what I did differently on Friday that Monday morning it is not working....

Comment: Remove are rename `"e:\ML\random.py"`, it masks the built-in `random` module. It triggers a circular import here which is why the `numpy.testing` module did not finish importing.

Comment: Oh my @MartijnPieters .... I did add new file this morning ... who knew!!! Now it works, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

run an additional import code, example:

```
import np.testing as npt
npt.assert_array_almost_equal(answer1, answer2 )
```