# AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'testing' when importing sklearn library

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I've imported numpy together with sklearn library but I got an Error
 `AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'testing'`

If I removed sklearn library from my code, it could run well.

the code is just like this:

```
import numpy as np
from kumparanian import ds
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer, TfidfTransformer, CountVectorizer, HashingVectorizer
```

Traceback:

```
File "<ipython-input-37-76f2395d81c0>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/LENOVO/Downloads/ds_assessment_v2/model.py', wdir='C:/Users/LENOVO/Downloads/ds_assessment_v2')

  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/LENOVO/Downloads/ds_assessment_v2/model.py", line 41, in <module>
    from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer, TfidfTransformer, CountVectorizer, HashingVectorizer

  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 76, in <module>
    from .base import clone

  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .utils import _IS_32BIT

  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from scipy.sparse import issparse

  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\__init__.py", line 228, in <module>
    from .base import *

  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\base.py", line 9, in <module>
    from scipy._lib._numpy_compat import broadcast_to

  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\_lib\_numpy_compat.py", line 17, in <module>
    _assert_warns = np.testing.assert_warns
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'testing'
```

Every suggestion is really appreciated.

Comment: Sorry. I will update it

Comment: Can you post the entire traceback? Have you created any python file that can shadow built-in modules?

Comment: Looks like an identical problem as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55106400/attributeerror-module-numpy-has-no-attribute-testing

Comment: Chris, I've read it and my code works if I removed sklearn

Answer (score 0):

In a first time, you can check if you have a problem with `numpy.training` by testing the code below:

```
import numpy as np
print(numpy.testing)
```

Which should return:

```
<module 'numpy.testing' from '[Python_directory]\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\testing\\__init__.py'>
```

If you get the same error as before (`AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'testing'`), then you could maybe try to update numpy as it would look like you're missing the module `numpy.testing`.

Tell us the result of that operation so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Run an additional import code, example:

```
import numpy.testing as npt
npt.assert_array_almost_equal(answer1, answer2)
```